# How are generated ids on trello?

Tags: trello, trello.net

I'm studying the Trello api and had the following doubts:
How is generated the id of the cards, boards and lists on trello?
Is it used some kind of hash?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must not make any assumptions on how id's are generated because if you rely on them, your code will eventually break. It is a good tone to generate id's in such a way, that  it will be impossible to predict them or make any assumptions. Hashes or  random numberas are a good way to achieve that. One of common ways to generate such id's is to use UUID's, but they are long.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but most hash algorithms that I know has a 32-character output (as well as the UUID's) or wven more, but the ids used on Trello have 25 characters, this is the center of my doubts. How are they generated?...